# draw diagram using modisco

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, eclipse-mdt

How can I draw uml diagram using modisco plugin? I have eclipse modelling tools and installed modisco plugin with with modisco model filter plugin. I managed to create a *.uml file from java project, however I can not build uml diagram from this model.

I found following [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-UML2Tools_FAQ#Can_I_create_a_diagram_from_UML2_model_.28.2A.uml_file.29.3F) which states that building diagram is easy. However when I right click on *.uml file to convert it to uml diagram there is no `Action` menu.

I have only following menu items in the file context menu:

[image]

What to do in order to generate uml diagram?

Answer (score 2):

With this discovery you will only discover the model of the uml file which is a  model. MoDisco is not a code generator but a code discoverer (Retro Modeling). There migth be tons of plugins to generate diagram from a uml model.

As your link says  :

> **Can I create a diagram from UML2 model (*.uml file)?**
>
> Yes, it's easy. To 'visualize' diagram from *.uml file use 'Initialize Class Diagram' action from the context menu of the file. There are also actions to initialize Component, Activity or State Machine diagram, choose the one you need. Appropriate diagram file (*.umlclass, *.umlcomp etc) will be created and then open. This feature is provided by GMF.

NB : Your link has no relation with moDisco but with UML2Tools you shall install it